# Python: Spyder switching between undocked editor window and spyder console

Tags: python, spyder

I'm running Spyder 3.2.4 in Windows 10

Despite my best efforts, my code is getting too wide to view in Spyder's default layout. I have therefore tried undocking the editor window. However, the undocked editor does not show up in the taskbar. Which leads me to the question, is there a way of switching between the main Spyder window and the undocked editor window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to go to the little cog menu on the right of the Editor and select the option *New window* to get a proper window.

This will be improved in Spyder 4 by allowing all our panes to generate a new window when undocked (Note: This is already implemented in Spyder master branch, in case you want to try it).

Comment: Thanks for the information, generating a new window works great

Comment: Glad you found it useful!